# curl issue, trying to open site with proxy server- php

Tags: php, curl

I am posting this question here because I know I will found an answer, as you helped me in my previous issues.

I am trying to access a website using proxy server and I am using this code:

```
function getPage($proxy,$proxyauth, $url, $referer, $agent, $header, $timeout) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

            $result['EXE'] = curl_exec($ch);
            $result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
            $result['ERR'] = curl_error($ch);
            $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result; 
    }
$agent2 = 'Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/7.1.32444/35.2883; U; ru) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10';
$result = getPage(
        "209.164.74.72:9786", // use valid proxy
        'username:pass',
        "http://www.whatismyip.com/",
        $agent2,
        0,
        5);
echo $result['EXE'];
```

it's working fine when I use it on my localhost but when I run it online its displaying me an error
**couldn't connect to host**

I am using hostgator shared server, also tried it on justhost shared server. but same error

Answer (score 1):

You may try to contact your provider directly
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/curl

It is possible that curl is allowed only for HTTP(s) and other ports are not allowed.